# Kegs head space

Tags: kegging

Could I buy a 16 gallon keg and only fill it with 10 gallons of beer and just fill all the headspace with co2? Will this cause the beer to absorb too much and be too carbonated?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes you can do that. As long as you have a pressure regulator the head space does not influence how much your beer will be carbonated. Remember that CO2 dissolution in beer mainly depends on pressure and temperature, so consult a table like this [this](http://www.kegerators.com/carbonation-table.php) and see what's best for your setup. Hope it helps.

Comment: Be sure to fill with sanitary solution and purge with cO2 before filling with Beer. If not the beer will contact with air and oxygen in the headspace.